# Unbounded function with finite integral

Tags: integration

I am facing the following condition in order to apply a theorem in a paper: $$
\phi \text { is twice differentiable on }(0, \infty) \text{ and it exists } \nu_2 \geq 3 \text{ such that }
$$

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\left[\phi^{\prime}\left(|x|^2 / 2\right)\right]^4(1+|x|)^{-\nu_2} d x<\infty.
$$

where $\phi$ is a measurable function, $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm.

It is stated the if $\phi(x) = log(x)$ then it is obvious that this condition holds with $\nu_2 \geq 3$.

I do not see how can this holds. Could you help me?

Comment: This is false. The function is not integrable near $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\phi (x)=\ln x$ is not even differentiable at $0$ and the conclusion fails for this function. However, if $\phi$ is continuously differentiable and if $\phi(x)=\ln x$ away from $0$, say for $|x|>1$, then the conclusion holds:

($\int_{\mathbb{R}} (|x|^2/2)^{-4}(1 + |x|)^{-\nu_2} < \infty$ is false).

For the first one split the integral into integral over $|x| \leq 1$ and integral over $|x|>1$. In the first part use boundedness of the integrand. For the second one note that $$\int_{|x|>1} (|x|^2/2)^{-4}(1 + |x|)^{-\nu_2} \leq 2^{-4}\int_{|x|>1} \frac  1 {|x|^{\nu_2+8}}< \infty$$

Comment: How do you bound the derivative of $\ln x$ in $\{x: |x| \le 1\}$?

Comment: You don't bring in log at all for $|x|<1$. $\phi'$ is bounded on bounded sets so $\phi^{\prime}\left(|x|^2 / 2\right)$ is bounded for $|x|<1$. @Thomas

Comment: What? What is your definition of a bounded set?

Comment: Could you explain better the first part? I do not get it. Thanks

Comment: @Eryna $(1+|x|)^{-\nu_2} \leq 1$ and $\phi'(|x|^{2}/2)$ is bounded by continuity of $\phi'$.

Comment: But $\phi' = 1/x$  is continuous on (0, ∞) and on (−∞, 0), i.e., for x > 0
and for x < 0, in other words, at every point in its domain. However, it is not a continuous function since its domain is not an interval. It has a single point of discontinuity, x = 0, and it has an infinite discontinuity there. This discontinuity point is an element of the set $\{x : |x| \leq 1\}$. Therefore you cannot apply the boundedness theorem. @geetha290krm

Comment: If you are still thinking of $\phi(x)=\ln x$ then your statement is false. There is no hope of proving it by differentiating $\ln x$ on all of $(0,\infty)$.  @Eryna

Comment: I agree with you @geetha290krm. I wrote the theorem as it is mentioned in the paper.